# execCommand bold fails in Firefox when all text is selected

Tags: javascript, firefox, wysiwyg, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm setting up to do some simple WYSIWYG editing using JavaScript, and I've run into an issue in Firefox that I don't get in Chrome or IE (recent versions of all). When all the text in my `contentEditable` span is selected, if I attempt to make it bold using `document.execCommand('bold',false,null)`, I receive a rather nondescript error message: "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure"

Here's some simple example code to easily reproduce the issue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function start(){

                var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
                edit.contentEditable = true;

                var button = document.getElementById('button');
                button.onclick = function(){

                    // Get the editable span
                    var edit = document.getElementById('edit');

                    // Select the contents of the span
                    var range = document.createRange();
                    range.selectNodeContents(edit);
                    var selection = window.getSelection();
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);

                    // Make the text bold
                    document.execCommand('bold',false,null);

                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="start();">
        <span id='edit'>Click on the button</span>
        <button id='button'>Bold It All!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Have I just run into a bug? If so, can anyone suggest a work-around solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Consider [filing it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=Editor). In short:

- The editor will attempt to wrap the `<span>` with a `<b>` (or another `<span>` when `useCSS`).
- This would remove the `<span>`.
- Therefore the code [checks](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/editor/libeditor/base/DeleteNodeTxn.cpp#40) that the parent of the `<span>` is editable, which it isn't.
- Boom!

Work-around: `contenteditable="true"` a real block element like `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks much. Looks like someone's already got a [report in on it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889940).

Comment: Any other alternatives you can think of to the div work-around? Unfortunately I'm working within an environment where another script I don't control requires the content in question to be in spans specifically.